# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation in laravel5.8.35

Tags: sqlite, laravel-5, controller

I am very new to laravel and sqlite and am trying to create a new 'dish' to my list of dishes, however, once I submit the creation form I receive the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL
>   constraint failed: dishes.user_id (SQL: insert into "dishes" ("name",
>   "price", "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (Supreme Pizza,
>   15, ?, 2019-09-29 05:43:42, 2019-09-29 05:43:42))

I have tried a number of different modifications in my web.php, DishController, UserController, and the create.blade.php form itself, but none of the changes have worked. There were some similar questions asked here but none of the solutions helped my particular problem either.

This is my web.php file

```
Route::resource('dish', 'DishController');
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('/show/{id}', 'UserController@show');
Route::get('/show/{id}', 'UserController@create');
Route::get('users/{user}',  ['as' => 'users.edit', 'uses' => 'UserController@edit']);
Route::patch('users/{user}/update',  ['as' => 'users.update', 'uses' => 'UserController@update']);

Route::get('/dish', 'DishController@index');
Route::get('/show/{id}', 'DishController@show');
Route::get('/dish/create', ['as' => 'dish.create', 'uses' => 'DishController@create']);
Route::get('dishes/{dish}',  ['as' => 'dish.edit', 'uses' => 'DishController@edit']);
Route::patch('dishes/{dish}/update',  ['as' => 'dishes.update', 'uses' => 'DishController@update']);
Route::get('/dish/{dish}', 'DishController@destroy');
```

The relevant part of my DishController:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $dishes = Dish::all();
        return view('dishes.index')->with('dishes', $dishes);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('dishes.create_form')->with('users', User::all());

    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'price' => 'required|integer|min:1',
            'user' => 'exists:user,id'
        ]);

        $dish = new Dish();
        $dish->name = $request->name;
        $dish->price = $request->price;
        $dish->user_id = $request->user;
        $dish->save();
        return redirect("dish/$dish->id");
    }
```

And the relevant part of my create_form:

```
<form method="POST" action='{{url("dish")}}'>
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <p><label>Name: </label><input type="text" name="name" value="{{old('name')}}"></p>
        <p><label>Price: </label><input type="text" name="price" value="{{old('price')}}"></p>
        <p><select name="Restaurant">
        @foreach ($users as $user)
            @if ($user->role == 'restaurant')
            <option value="{{$user->id}}" selected="selected">{{$user->name}}</option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
        </select></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create">
    </form>
```

The general idea is that I list my users that have a 'role' of 'restaurant'
and when I click on one, it takes me to the dishes they have (i.e. lists all dishes with selected user_id), and the option to create a new dish.

When I try to create a new dish, I input all necessary data and submit the form but I get the error message as seen in the Title. It says that dishes.user_id is null, and shows it as '?'.

This is odd since the POST data shows that:

```
        name = "Supreme Pizza"
        price = "15"
        Restaurant = "7" (which is correct)
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is there in `$request->user`? I doubt the user_id is not getting set properly.

Comment: @Zeshan I'm not quite sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP controller you are using $request->user. which i don't see in your HTML Form. So, If you want to add current user. You can use Auth.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'price' => 'required|integer|min:1',
        'user' => 'exists:user,id'
    ]);
    $dish = new Dish();
    $dish->name = $request->name;
    $dish->price = $request->price;
    $dish->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $dish->save();
    return redirect("dish/$dish->id");
}
```

Please Also use Auth in top of Controller

```
use Auth;
```

Comment: I now get 
```
Validation rule unique requires at least 1 parameters.
```

Comment: Yes, but your error NOT NULL constraint failed: dishes.user_id  is about user_id. which you are not defining.